# Multiple version of python but only one works

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, virtual-environment

Sorry I know there many questions like this but for a reason or another (probabily even my ignorance) they don't work.

I use windows 10 and I need different version of python 3.x for different projects.

This the problem: I install a version of python and I use it for develop some projects (each one in his virtual environment), then new versions of python come out and I want to upgrade for my new projects.
So I uninstall the old version and I install the new version but my old projects do not work anymore (because they were developed with the old version). I can upgrade the projects I'm still working on but I don't want to upgrade all of them.

The solution should be to install multiple version of python and to create a virtual environment using the right python version. Right? Please give me an advice even on this.

I installed python 3.9 and it set the environment variables. All seem to works.

Then I installed python 3.3 (it doesn't set environment variables). Using the launcher I can launch it or create a virtual environment (using venv like raccomandated):

```
py -3.3
py -3.3 -m venv myvenv33
```

but I can't install packages. The directory `C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python33\Lib\site-packages` is empty while in `...\python39\Lib\site-packages` there's pip and setuptools.

The command

```
py -3.9 -m pip
```

gives the pip menù, while

```
py -3.3 -m pip
```

gives `No module named pip`

I can activate the 3.3 virtual environment and install packages like this:

```
(myvenv33) E:\progetti\Envs> pip install mypackage
```

but the package is installated globally: it appears in the `pip list` even when the env is deactivated. Using a 3.9 env this doesn't happen and all works fine.

I tried many things (for example I set the environment variables even for python3.3 by myself, I used pyenv, I tried to install pip using get-pip) but I can't find a solution.

I prefer to use venv and not virtualenv because is raccomanded (but I tried even that).

Thank for your help, I'm learning, maybe I miss some basic

**Edit:**

In comment asked what I did with get-pip.py

Python3.9 have pip but python 3.3 doesn't so I tried to install it:

```
py -3.3 get-pip.py
```

Now it appear in `...\python33\Lib\site-packages`

```
py -3.3 -m pip
```

gives the pip menù and

```
py -3.3 -m pip --version
```

gives the version of pip for python 3.3

but I have to use the `py -3.3 -m` prefix even inside `myvenv33` and when I install a package that is installed in python 3.3 site-packages but is global, not restricted to the venv:

```
(myvenv33) E:\progetti\Envs>py -3.3 -m pip install mypackage
```

Those both see mypackage:

```
(myvenv33) E:\progetti\Envs>py -3.3 -m pip list
E:\progetti\Envs>py -3.3 -m pip list
```

Comment: Why are you uninstalling Python in the first place? They can live quite happily alongside each other. At any rate, what happened when you tried to install `pip` with `get-pip.py`?

Comment: I uninstalled python to have only one version (like an upgrade), but let's say that was before the facts in this question, to better explain the expected result. Now I'm trying to install more version side by side. Using get-pip.py I can install pip but the package get installed globally

Comment: `get-pip.py` has a `--user` command-line argument, so it installs in `C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python3X\site-packages` (where X is the minor version number). The `pip` executable is installed in `C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python3X\Scripts`.

Comment: Yes it works like you say and yet the packages are installed globally even when my venv is activated

Comment: Consider using conda or pipenv instead, both support different python versions without the hassle of installing multiple versions on you machine. Simple comparison: https://medium.com/@krishnaregmi/pipenv-vs-virtualenv-vs-conda-environment-3dde3f6869ed